# Properties set on __proto__ override directly set properties in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

With this html:

```
<select><option>hi</option></select>

<script type="text/javascript">

var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];

select.__proto__.setValue = "foo";
select.setValue = "bar";

alert(select.setValue);

</script>
```

In Firefox and Opera, the output is "bar", but in Chrome, the output is "foo". If I skip the `__proto__` definition, all browsers output "bar".

How do I get Chrome (8.0) to output the object specific value of the property, instead of the value set on the prototype?

Comment: Works as expected in Chrome 9 and 10, so that's most likely a bug. As a side note don't mess with builtin objects, that still holds true for HTMLElements.

Comment: @Ivo: I can confirm it doesn't work in Chrome 8.  As a side note, I guess that's what happens when several browsers attempt to implement the same non-standard feature - at least one of them is bound to get it wrong :-p

Comment: @AndyE I'm sure I could find a bug on this somewhere on the issue list, that is if I spend the next two days searching for it.

Comment: Thanks Ivo, updating to the dev channel (currently 9.0.*) fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comments above, this is resolved in the current version of Chrome.